# Html agility pack Addressing

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

in this Html

```
<div class="contacts-list">
    <h4 class="title">Contact</h4>
                <div class="contact-phone">
            <span class="icon"><i class="ee-phone"></i></span><span class="type">تلفن</span>
            <span class="contact-data">
                                        <a dir='auto' href='tel:05138946697'>05138946697</a>                                    </span>
        </div>
```

I have to extract the value of the "a" tag but I must be sure it is inside a "div" tag with a "contact-phone" class.

I don't really understand how I have to do this can someone help me?

Comment: I don't know html agility pack but since it's xpath based you should be able to use `//div[contains(@class,'contact-phone')]/a` (note: this will also select div element with a class like contact-phone-something)

Comment: @MarkBaijens the link is nested into a `span` tag, so `/a` is not going to target it.

Comment: @derloopkat `//a` then

Answer (score 1):

so I get the value I need like this using the HTML Agility pack and Xpath

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='" + "contact-phone" + "']/span[@class='"+ "contact-data" + "']/a"))
                        {
                            value = node.InnerText;
                        }
```

Comment: If you're familiar with JS `querySelector`, try NuGet addon `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack`. It provides `HtmlNode.QuerySelector` method that accepts the same query syntax as in JS.